# Сортировка по двум произвольным полям ACF в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Есть два поля - цена и цена со скидкой. И как обычно надо сделать сортировку по возрастанию или убыванию цены товара . Пример:

- **1999 руб**
- **2222 руб (цена со скидкой)** 4000 руб
- **3500 руб**

Вот такие у меня параметры запроса:

```
{
   "categories":"shkafy-i-polky",
   "meta_query":{
      "relation":"AND",
      "1":{
         "relation":"AND",
         "query_one":{
            "key":"price",
            "type":"NUMERIC"
         },
         "query_two":{
            "key":"price_sale",
            "type":"NUMERIC"
         }
      }
   },
   "orderby":{
      "query_two":"ASC",
      "query_one":"ASC"
   }
}
```

В результате сначала идет вывод всех товаров без скидки с сортировкой цены по возрастанию, а после идут товары со скидкой, так же по возрастанию. Надо сделать что бы они шли вперемешку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожелению, с помощью средств WordPress это сделать крейне тежело без извращения.

С Вашего масива аргументов, должно выводить посты, из категории `shkafy-i-polky`, у которых указана цена `price`, и цена по скидке `price_sale` в одно и тоже время, а если, например, не будет указана цена по скидке? Тогда у вас товар не попадет в список постов для вывода. Так как логика работает через указаный `relation` `AND`.

Далее, у вас осуществляется сортировка сначало по цене со скидкой, по возрастанию `query_two` `ASC`, а далее по обычной цене, при этом внутри предидущей сортировки, `query_one` `ASC`. Также, если цена будет напрмер `10.3`, `5.13` и т.д., то сортировка не должна работать корреткно с `type`
`NUMERIC`, так как из документации, `NUMERIC` будет работать только с целіми числами. Нужно использывать `DECIMAL`.

Наиболее логичным вариантом для меня в даной ситуации, есть логика по принципу:

1. Получить список всех нужных постов(товаров) для вывода с их актуальной ценой
2. Отсортивровать список по цене
3. Запустить цикл вывода по уже отсортированому списку

Да, будет два запроса к БД, но будет корректный правильный результат вконце. Если нужно обойтись одным запросом, то без SQL-запроса обойтись никак.

Пример кода и масивов аргументов для логики, описаной выше, написан на php, но составить интеграцию для комерции не составит труда я думаю. Итак, сначало получи список нужных нам постов(товаров):

- Масив агрументов, для получения полного списка нужных товаров\постов, который мы будем сортировать далее

  ```
  $argc = [
  'categories' => 'shkafy-i-polky', // Нужная категория
      'meta_query' => [
          'relation' => 'OR', // Если одно, из условий ниже(ключи) существуют
          // Массив условий normal, добавляет в список посты/товары, у которых есть цена
          'normal' => [
              'key' => 'price',
              'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)',
              'compare' => 'EXISTS'
          ],
          // Массив условий ext, добавляет в список товары, у которых есть цена, и в тоже время цена по скидке.
          'ext' => [
              'relation' => 'AND',
              [
                  'key' => 'price',
                  'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)',
                  'compare' => 'EXISTS'
              ],
              [    'key' => 'price_sale',
                    'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)'
              ]
          ]
      ]
  ];
  ```
- Далее получим список `ID` всех нужных товаров, и составим массив с их поточной ценой(обычная цена или со скидкой)

  ```
  $list = new WP_Query($argc);
  $sorted = [];
  if($list->have_posts()) : while ($list->have_posts()) : $list->the_post();
      $sale = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price_sale', true); // Проверяем ли установлена цена по скидке
      $sorted[$post->ID] = (!empty($sale)) ? $sale : get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price', true) ; // Если цена по скидке не установлена или она пуста, равна 0, то берем цену без скидки
  endwhile;
  endif;
  ```

  Возможны дополнительные пареметры такие как `posts_per_page`, `post_type`, `post_status`, но они не рассматриваются, так как выше написан пример масива с правильной структурой и базовыми параметрами.
  В итоге мы имеем массив `$sorted`, где ключ имеет `ID` товара, а его значение это поточная активная цена(простая цена или цена со скидкой). Осталось дело за малым, отсортировать масив с ценами по возростанию его значений командой `asort()`.

  ```
  if(!empty($sorted)) $tmp = asort($sorted);
  ```

Потом, для проверки можно убедится, что наш массив отсортирован по возрастанию цены, например комендой `print_r($tmp);`. И просто для удобства работы с `ID` постов\товаров, превратим ключи нашего отсортированого масива в значения командой `$ids = array_keys($tmp);`.

В итоге, мы имеем масив `$ids`, каждое значение которого есть `ID` поста\продукта, которые стоят в порядке актуальной цены на продукт. Что с ним делать ? Можно просто запустить новый цикл с выводом наших отсортированых постов\товаров. Можно использывать любой из доступных способов, наиболее простой это просто запустить запрос с параметром `post__in`, передав ему наш массив `$ids`.